# In the hyperbolic geometry, is there a range of $\pi$?

Tags: pi, hyperbolic-geometry

In Euclidean space, $\pi$ is the constant value $3.14159\dots$ 
But I tried to measure the value of $\pi$ and found that $\pi$ is not constant!

So I wonder if there is a range of $\pi$. If so, is $\pi$ in hyperbolic geometry bigger than $3.14159\dots$ (in Euclidean geometry)?

Comment: yes, in hyperbolic geometry the length of circles is greater than $2 \pi r$ not sure if there is a maximun value, (I doubt it) PS angle measure is the normal (euclidean) radians anyway.

Comment: How are you defining your hyperbolic $\pi$ (which I'll denote $\hat{\pi}$)? If it's a circle's circumference-to-diameter ratio, then
$$\hat{\pi} = \frac{2\pi\sinh{r}}{2r}=\pi\;\frac{\sinh{r}}{r} = \pi\left(\;1 + \frac{r^2}{3!} + \frac{r^4}{5!} + \frac{r^6}{7!} + \cdots \;\right)$$
which tends to infinity as radius $r$ increases. (Note that $\hat{\pi}=\pi$ for infinitely-small circles, $r=0$. :)

Answer (score 1):

As Blue noted in a comment, the range of perimeter/diameter ratio of hyperbolic circles is $(\pi,\infty)$. Blue's comment contains an exact formula; I'll instead give a qualitative analysis.

One way to realize the hyperbolic plane is the Euclidean disk $\{x\in\mathbb R^2:|x|<1\}$ on which the length of a curve $\gamma$ is computed is 
$$\int_{\gamma} \frac{|d\gamma(t)|}{ 1- |\gamma(t)|^2}$$
(Often there is a constant of $4$ here, to normalize the curvature to $-1$. This constant would cancel out in the computations below, anyway.)

Let's consider the circle of *Euclidean* radius $r\in (0,1)$ centered at $0$. Its hyperbolic radius is 
$$r_h = \int_0^r \frac{1}{1-t^2}\,dt$$
and its hyperbolic perimeter is 
$$p_h  =  \frac{2\pi r}{1-r^2}$$
The integral  can be taken exactly, but the desired conclusion can be obtained without doing this. Indeed,
$$r_h < \int_0^r \frac{1}{1-r^2}\,dt = \frac{r}{1-r^2}
= \frac{p_h}{2\pi}
$$
This tells you that the "hyperbolic $\pi$", $p_h/(2r_h)$, is  strictly greater than the Euclidean $\pi$. To see that "hyperbolic $\pi$" can be arbitrarily large, note that 
$$r_h < \int_0^r \frac{1}{1-x}\,dx = -\log(1-r) $$
which implies $p_h/r_h\to \infty$ as $r\to 1$ (e.g., with L'Hospital's rule).